# Set AWS SNS - SMS Type on REST Request

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, post, postman, amazon-sns

I am trying to send a SMS message to AWS SNS via Postman, but when I try to add the SMSType to the request params, it doesn't override the default SMS type.

also didn't find an explanation on this in their documentation.

Any idea how to change this setting with REST request? (same question for other settings such as: 'OriginationNumber', 'SenderID', MaxPrice' etc..)

[What I tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXIvL.png)